# Multiple SFML RenderWindow in separate threads

Tags: linux, multithreading, c++11, sfml

Having some trouble with SFML (version 2.1).

Trying to create two instances of sf::RenderWindow on two separate threads. Application works for some time (amount of time is not constant) and then eventually will crash due to assertion:

```
testapp: ../../src/xcb_conn.c:186: write_vec: Assertion `!c->out.queue_len' failed.
```

Test piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>

void WindowOne ()
{
    sf::RenderWindow* wnd = new sf::RenderWindow (sf::VideoMode(800,600),
                                                  "Window 1");

    while (wnd->isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (wnd->pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                wnd->close();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }

        wnd->clear(sf::Color::White);

        wnd->display();

    }
    delete wnd;
}

void WindowTwo ()
{    
    sf::RenderWindow* wnd = new sf::RenderWindow (sf::VideoMode(800,600),
                                                  "Window 2");

    while (wnd->isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (wnd->pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                wnd->close();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }

        wnd->clear(sf::Color::White);

        wnd->display();

    }
    delete wnd;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    XInitThreads();

    std::thread thread1 (WindowOne);
    std::thread thread2 (WindowTwo);

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Please, help me to find out, what am I doing wrong, or can I even do such things.

**Edit:**

Forgot to mention that it crashes at:

```
wnd->display();
```